# How to get only the first few matches of mysql SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, select

> ```
>  if(strcmp($sort,"popular") == 0){
>       "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id IN ($idResults) ORDER BY rating";
>  }
> ```

I first selected the projects by genres the resulting IDs are in $idResults, then i want them all sorted by rating.
It may be a very long list of results, so now my question is how can i adjust the SELECT so that I only get the first say 7 results(at the next call from 7 to 14, etc)

Thanks in advance ;)

---

I now tried,

> $query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id IN ".implode(',',$idResults)." ORDER BY rating LIMIT ".$count.", 7";

cause I got a php error, that there is an array to string conversion, so i added a "," after each element in the array and imploded it to a string.

but if i continue doing:

> ```
>   $result = $this->dbc->query($query);
>   $resultLines = array();
>   while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
>       $resultLines[] = $row;
>   }
>   return resultLines;
> ```

i get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in ******* on line 66

so i suspect something is still wrong in my query, but i cant figure out what.

Comment: Is this a question about pagination?

Comment: where does `$idResults` come? how long? how many values in `$idResults`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LIMIT` clause - `LIMIT 7`.

For subsequent queries, you can use the full `LIMIT` clause - i.e. `LIMIT offset, count`. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id IN ($idResults) ORDER BY rating LIMIT 0, 7;
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id IN ($idResults) ORDER BY rating LIMIT 7, 7;
```